# Binary Search using Java on a UTF-8 encoded text file where line size is not fixed

Tags: java, file-io, binary-search

I have a tab separated UTF-8 file, where the records are sorted on one field. But, the line size is not fixed, so cannot jump into a particular position directly. How can I perform binary search on this?

Example:

line 1: Alfred Brendel              /m/011hww   /m/0crsgs6,/m/0crvt9h,/m/0cs5n_1,/m/0crtj4t,/m/0crwpnw,/m/0cr_n2s,/m/0crsgyh

line 2: Rupert Sheldrake                /m/011ybj   /m/0crtszs

Comment: What do you mean by line size not fixed? Can you show one test case?

Comment: So, in short, he means the length of each line is not uniform.  (Just to clarify for other readers.)

Answer (score 3):

You know the number of bytes your hole file contains. Lets say `n`
-> search-interval `[l, r]` with `l=0`, `r=n`.

- Estimate the middle of your search-interval `m=(r-l)/2`. At this location go as much bytes to the left (right would also work) until you find a tab-character (byte==9 *(9 is the ASCII and UTF8 code for a tab)*) [lets name this position `mReal` ] and decode the one line starting that tab.
- determine if you have to take the first 'half' (=> new search-interval is `[l, mReal]`)  or the second 'half' (=> new search-interval is `[mReal, r]`) for the next search step.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your solution. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: At least on my computer \t == 9 [in ASCII and UTF8]

Comment: My comment wasn't intending to imply you were incorrect on the ASCII code, only that it wasn't clear that was what you meant by saying byte==9.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Sorry I misunderstood your comment [happens sometimes when you are not a native speaker]

Comment: The meaning was ambiguous even for a native English speaker.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: @MrSmith42 : I have implemented this, but getting java.io.UTFDataFormatException around byte 0 Exception. I am very naive in random file handling. Could you please tell me where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can guess the line length from the file size

Yet When you can't even guess the length of the lines then I think it will be better to chose from generating a random number.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourTokenizer {

    public static final String EPF_EOL = "\t";

    public static final int READ_SIZE = 4 * 1024 ;

    /** The EPF stream buffer. */
    private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    /** The EPF stream. */
    private InputStream stream = null;

    public YourTokenizer(final InputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    private String getNextLine() throws IOException {
        int pos = buffer.indexOf(EPF_EOL);
        if (pos == -1) {
            // eof-of-line sequence isn't available yet, read more of the file
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[READ_SIZE];
            final int readSize = stream.read(bytes, 0, READ_SIZE);


            buffer.append(new String(bytes));
            pos = buffer.indexOf(EPF_EOL);
            if (pos == -1) {
                if (readSize < READ_SIZE) {
                    // we have reached the end of the stream and what we're looking for still can't be found
                    throw new IOException("Premature end of stream");
                }
                return getNextLine();
            }
        }

        final String data = buffer.substring(0, pos);
        pos += EPF_EOL.length();
        buffer = buffer.delete(0, pos);
        return data;
    }

}
```

end in main :

```
final InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
 final YourTokenizer tokenizer = new YourTokenizer(stream);

 String line = tokenizer.getNextLine();
 while(line != line) {
   //do something
   line = tokenizer.getNextLine();
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this would be used in a binary search of the file?

Comment: this give you all tokens separated by EPF_EOL string. So you can easy receive all fields

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the middle of bytes.  From there you can find the end of that line and you can read the next line from that point.  If you need to search back, take a one quarter point, or three quarters and find the line each time.  Eventually you will narrow it down to one line.